# random html code in a textarea

Tags: html

Does anyone know why I am getting random html code in my textarea

this is what I'm talking about:
http://gyazo.com/125e31ac593149ba7b362ab5ed4ff585

Here is the code I Have:

```
<form id="f1" action="contact.php" method="post">
  Your Name: 
  <input type="text" name="cf_name" /><br/>
  Your e-mail:
  <input type="email" name="cf_email"/><br/>
  Message:<br/>
  <textarea form="f1" name="cf_message"/><br/>
  <input type="submit" value="Send"/>
  <input type="reset" value="Clear"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mismatched quotes:

```
<input type="submit'  value="Send"/>
```

Also, the `<textarea>` tag is not self-closing. You need to add a `</textarea>` closing tag:

```
<textarea form="f1" name="cf_message">
</textarea>
```

See more info at [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea) (specifically the part where it mentions "both the starting and ending tag are mandatory").

Answer (score 0):

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jats_ptl/2p7EY/1/)

```
<form id="f1" action="contact.php" method="post">
  Your Name: 
  <input type="text" name="cf_name" /><br/>
  Your e-mail:
  <input type="email" name="cf_email"/><br/>
  Message:<br/>
  <textarea form="f1" name="cf_message"></textarea><br/>
  <input type="submit"  value='Send'/>
  <input type="reset" value="Clear"/>
</form>
```

Comment: You should be consistent in your quote usage and also explain why this works where the OP's code block doesn't.